# Python Pandas select column by value by column of colnames

Tags: pandas, dataframe, select

I have a column containing the names of certain columns of a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3':['col1', 'col2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I would like to create a col4 with values from either col1 (first row) or col2 (second row), based on the names in col3.

Update: in the real problem, there are duplicate values. Solved it for now with the following anti-pattern as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 1], 'col2': [3, 4, 1], 'col3':['col1','col2', 'col1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


# Solution with result I intended, even though not ideal 
df["col4"] = 0 # initialize integer column 
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    df.loc[i, "col4"] = (df.loc[i, df["col3"][i]])

df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['col3'])
df['col4'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     3  col1     1
1     2     4  col2     4
```

Comment: Thank you! 
This indeed seems to be the "official way" to go. 

Working with pandas for years, yet never heard of reindex and/or factorize. Having R-background this seems to be quite a complicated construction.

Comment: @Krisselack there used to be a `lookup` function that was doing this directly, but,  unfortunately, it was deprecated

Comment: Of course, in the real problem, there are duplicate entries.

Comment: The you should probably aggregate first, maybe open a new question with a clear example

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with the following anti-pattern:
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    df.loc[i, "col4"] = (df.loc[i, df["col3"][i]])

Answer (score 1):

you can use [df.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)

```
df['col4']=df.apply(lambda row:df.eval(df.col3)[row.name][row.name],axis=1)
df
Out[233]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     3  col1     1
1     2     4  col2     4
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain the code to me? 

As far as I understand: lambda df.eval runs per column -> Selection of columns.
Why is the [row.name][row.name] clause necessary?

Comment: row.name is index of the row to pick just the required values , so [row.name][row.name] will be [0,0] first time , [1][1] 2nd time.  mozway's solution looks more efficient